# RestSharp deserialize utf-8 content into a class

Tags: c#, rest, utf-8, restsharp

I am making a REST API call and the response JSON consists of UTF8-8 encoding. How can I deserialize into a class and have the encoding intact? Though this code doesn't fail but I lose the encoding.

```
var request = new RestRequest("some url", Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Accept-Charset","utf-8");
request.AddHeader("Accept","*/*");
request.AddHeader("ContentType","application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
request.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
request.AddUrlSegment("FrameworkGUID", FrameworkGUID);
var response = Client.Execute<RootObject>(request);
var str = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response.Content));
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(str);
```

JSON response:

```
{"fullStatement":"Extend polynomial identities to include factoring with complex numbers. For example, rewrite x\u00b2 + 4 as (x + 2i)(x \u2013 2i).","language":"en"}
```

**Edit:** I wasn't debugging correctly. The deserialization is happening fine. In fact you just need this code:

```
var request = new RestRequest("some url", Method.GET);
request.AddUrlSegment("FrameworkGUID", FrameworkGUID);
var response = Client.Execute<RootObject>(request);
return response.Data;
```

Comment: `var str = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response.Content))` that doesn't make any sense. You get the response content already as astring. But then you try to decode it into a byte array using ASCII encoding, followed by trying to transform the ASCII bytes back into a string using UTF-8 encoding. What is the purpose of this rather pointless dance? You have the content string already, why don't you simply deserialize the content string? (o.O)?

Comment: I tried to deserialize the string and it deserializes fine, i just dont get the special characters. So I tried something else. This is how the json response string comes back as: {"fullStatement":"Extend polynomial identities to include factoring with complex numbers. *For example, rewrite x\u00b2 + 4 as (x + 2i)(x \u2013 2i).*","language":"en"}

Comment: What do you mean with "special characters" exactly? Text encodings are not about "special characters", text encodings are about how character (special or not) are encoded as bytes/octets or sequences of bytes/octets. I think you are going down the wrong path here. Show what an example of the content string is (with special characters), and describe how exactly the resulting RootObject should look like (you don't need to explain any object property or field, only thos that demonstrate and are affected by the "special characters")

Comment: With regard to your last comment: Please put this information in the question itself (you can edit your question). It is crucial information about your problem and thus needs to be a part of the question itself and not be buried in some comment ;-)

Comment: By the way, the JSON example in comment is deserialized just fine by Json.NET, including unescaping/decoding the Unicode character codes `\u00b2` (`²`) and `\u2013` (`–`). If that is _really_ the JSON data you have problems with, it is not the deserialization. Perhaps your problem is with outputting (or further processing of) this _fullStatement_ string somewhere, using a console or a a display font that does not provide glyphs for `²` and `–` and thus fails to render them...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I wasn't looking at the correct record while debugging.